# how to increase Rate limit in Instagram for website?

Tags: php, wordpress, instagram

I have create Slider With Instagram Image but suddenly give a error "The maximum number of requests per hour has been exceeded."

I have checked Online and find My App Rate limit Is 500 for sandbox
 I have Used Below code  For get image

```
<?php
       $tag = 'User_ID';
            $access_token = "access_token";
            $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$tag.'/media/recent?access_token='.$access_token;
             $result  = URL_P($url);
             $decoded_results = json_decode($result,true);
 ?>
```

AND URL_P Function Below

```
<?php
function URL_P($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
 ?>
```

Comment: add quotes around the url like this `$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$tag.'/media/recent?access_token='.$access_token';`

Answer (score 0):

sandbox accounts usually have lower request limits, Usually its 500 for sandbox and 5000 for live. Here is a link for the limits https://instagram.com/developer/limits/

Register a new client and use it with a limit, so it doesn't grab everything on every request.

$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$tag.'/media/recent?client_id='.$client_id.'&count='.$count;